# Implicitly initializing firebase in a React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

I'm attempting to combine [implicit initialization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#reserved-urls) for Firebase and a React app (created using CRA) as it seems like a good way to ensure I don't need to worry too much about configuring for different environments.

However, when running the app, if I make any attempt to use the `firebase` object I get the error `Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

My index file has the Firebase files included before the app files and if I put a breakpoint in the Firebase-provided `init` then I can see that it is initializing the `firebase` object.

[image]

The `App` component is the one that comes with the CRA boilerplate:

```
mport React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/functions'

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const helloWorld = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld')
  helloWorld().then(result => console.log({ result }))

  return (
  ...
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you check: 1) if the content of the `init.js` seems to be correct? 2) if your `firebase.functions().httpsCallable(` is somehow getting called before the initialization in `init.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong. The `init` script was being called correctly and creating a global `firebase` object, which I was then overriding with my imports.

I removed the two imports in my component and changed the `helloWorld` declaration:

```js
const helloWorld = window.firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld')
```

The typescript linter then complains that `firebase` doesn't exist on Window, so I've added a `global.d.ts` file containing this:

```
interface Window {
  firebase: any
}
```

At some point, I'll work out the correct type for it, but it's got me past the problem.